# Sort an array of objects based on regex match ignoring the missing items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects called `attachments` where I need to sort based on `sort_based_on_this_order` array

If the `sort_based_on_this_order` array size is 7 items and array of objects size is 10 items. The array of objects has to be sorted in the order of 7 items followed by unspecified (missing) in last.

```js
var sort_based_on_this_order = ['1666433101760', '1666434169913', '1666434194815', '1666432849037', '1666432764144', '1666432044571', '1666432742444']

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(
  attachments.sort((a, b) => {
    let k1 = a.filename.match(/\b[0-9]{13}(?=\.[^.]+$)/)
    let k2 = b.filename.match(/\b[0-9]{13}(?=\.[^.]+$)/)
    let i1 = sort_based_on_this_order.indexOf(k1[0])
    let i2 = sort_based_on_this_order.indexOf(k2[0])
    return i1 > i2 ? 1 : -1
  }), null, 4) + '</pre>')
```

```html
<script>
var attachments = [{
  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978911/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666433926644.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978911
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978910/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666434169913.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978910
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978909/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666434048280.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978909
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978907/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666433101760.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978907
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978905/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666434194815.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978905
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978904/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432849037.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978904
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978903/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432801510.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978903
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978902/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432764144.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978902
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978901/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432044571.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978901
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978900/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432742444.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978900
}]
</script>
```

Comment: The data structure in your question is an array of objects. It is not, and has nothing to do with, JSON. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @CodeGuy simplify the example to show  the exact problem you're having, no one  should have  to sift through  all  your  extraneous data to guess your expected   outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some item is missing,then you can assign it with an `Infinity` value

```js
var attachments = [{
  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978911/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666433926644.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978911
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978910/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666434169913.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978910
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978909/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666434048280.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978909
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978907/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666433101760.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978907
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978905/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666434194815.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978905
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978904/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432849037.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978904
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978903/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432801510.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978903
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978902/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432764144.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978902
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978901/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432044571.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978901
}, {

  "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978900/",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432742444.jpg",
  "instance": 194338021,
  "xform": 740320,
  "id": 82978900
}]
var sort_based_on_this_order = ['1666433101760', '1666434169913', '1666434194815', '1666432849037', '1666432764144', '1666432044571', '1666432742444']

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(
  attachments.sort((a, b) => {
    let k1 = a.filename.match(/\b[0-9]{13}(?=\.[^.]+$)/)
    let k2 = b.filename.match(/\b[0-9]{13}(?=\.[^.]+$)/)
    let i1 = sort_based_on_this_order.indexOf(k1[0])
    let i2 = sort_based_on_this_order.indexOf(k2[0])
    if(i1==-1){
      i1 = Infinity
     }
    if(i2==-1){
      i2 = Infinity
     }
    return i1 > i2 ? 1 : -1
  }), null, 4) + '</pre>')
```

Comment: @pilchard Nice to see you again,and it's a great improvement

Comment: @CodeGuy,what's your expected result order

Comment: @CodeGuy seems just need to change `-Infinity` to `Infinity`,see my updated answer